# Problems running the ripple emulator on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to run the ripple emulator on Visual Studio, however I cannot seem to get pass the **cannot find module './lib/plugin'error** as follows:

C:\Users[user name]\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Cordova\Cordova>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat

*Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: E:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\VISUAL STUDIO\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\FUBXMEK2.O2B\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Cannot find module './lib/plugin'*

PS: The previous error I got was cannot find module 'q' however this was resolved by running npm install from CLI.

I am trying to create a Cordova application using Visual Studio. Any ideas how I can resolve the above error?

Comment: I managed to solved it by Clearing the cordova cache. Not sure what the reason was in the first place but it now builds and runs the ripple emulator. Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova –> Cordova Tools -> Clear Cordova Cache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems something went wrong while installing vs-mda, you can try following to re-install:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open cmd
3. npm install -g [path to vs-mda example C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda]
4. npm install -g [path to vs-mda-targets example C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets]

**OR**

1. Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache
   [image]

Comment: I tried the above two methods and still have the same problem "cannot find module 'q' "  .any help ?

Comment: I used "npm install -g q" in the CLI, updated my nodejs version (download it manually from the site), then used the "Clear Cordova Cache" on my project and it launched ;-)

Comment: try removing BLD folder and rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

For the second method above (Clear Cordova Data) try running visual studio as administrator if it fails the first time around.