# Cannot find module 'q'

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have met this trouble in both VS2013Up4 and VS2015Pre. My OS is Win8.1 Pro x64. The detail message about the error:

> Cannot find module 'q'    MDAVSCLI  1 1  WinJSToDo.

And I can get nothing from double click it. Please help me. ORZ...
Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2013 update 4 with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova extension on Windows 8.1. I create a new Cordova JavaScript Blank project and then trigger a build, it turns out to be below building error:

> Error 2 Cannot find module 'q' C:\Users\penlv\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\MDAVSCLI 1 1
>   BlankCordovaApp1

Seems many other users run into the same issue. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981782/problems-running-the-ripple-emulator-on-visual-studio-2013) if works.
And also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app).

I tried but still have the same error.

Finally i have 'Cannot find module' error fixed:

1. copy 'lib' and 'resource' folder from 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\vs-mda' to 'C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda'
2. in 'C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda' folder, run `npm install` command

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my "User Account Control" was switched on (Windows 8.1).

The solution was to run Visual Studio as Administrator, and then clear your cordova cache, and rebuild.